# How to merge two JSON Objects into one in php?

Tags: php, json

How to merge two json objects into one ? both the json objects have similar structure 
I have tried using below code , but its now working

```
<?php
$requestUrl="http://www.reddit.com/r/deals.json?limit=10&t=hour";
$requestUrl1="http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdeals.json?limit=10&t=hour";
$data=file_get_contents($requestUrl);
$data1=file_get_contents($requestUrl1);
$array1 = json_decode($data);
$array2 = json_decode($data1);
$json = json_encode(array_combine( $array1, $array2 )); //line 8
echo $json;
?>
```

EDIT : Sorry , Adding error details

Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in "URL" on line 8
null

Edit : Adding JSON Objects $data and $data1  ( to keep it simple i just added only one item for object)

```
$data = '{
  "kind": "Listing",
  "data": {
    "modhash": "ynp0pgdyf6bd03faef14e60cf6ab97f2e396bb81545ea57578",
    "children": [
      {
        "kind": "t3",
        "data": {
          "domain": "self.deals",
          "banned_by": null,
          "media_embed": {

          },
          "subreddit": "deals",
          "selftext_html": "&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Some of you may have seen this already, but CreditSesame is running a promo for the month of November where you refer 6 friends and receive a $150 Amazon Gift Card. I&amp;#39;m hoping we can get a legitimate referral train started so we can all make some easy money. Should come in handy for Christmas shopping.&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;THIS OFFER IS FOR THE US ONLY &amp;amp; YOU HAVE TO BE AT LEAST 18 YEARS OLD.&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;What is CreditSesame?&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;It&amp;#39;s pretty much just like CreditKarma. It shows you your credit score, why you got the score and what you can do to improve it.&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;Most importantly, there is NO CREDIT CARD NEEDED to sign up because it&amp;#39;s FREE. You can of course buy some advanced features, but that&amp;#39;s not necessary.&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;Now, you do have to provide legitimate information, as it uses your SSN to get your credit report. They pull your credit report in a way that won&amp;#39;t hurt your credit score according to their site. (Someone may be able to better explain this than me)&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;Referral Train&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;Here are some basic guidelines to try to get this thing running smoothly: Once you sign up, you can get your referral link by hovering over your name on in the top-right corner and selecting &amp;quot;Invite a friend&amp;quot; from the menu. Paste that link as a reply to who you signed up under in this thread. Each person only needs 6 referrals, so don&amp;#39;t keep signing up under someone when they already have 6 replies. Keep &amp;quot;forking&amp;quot; and spreading the referrals around so that everyone has at least a chance to get a few. Please remove your referral link once you receive 6 referrals so everyone knows you have completed yours. So to get this started, here is my referral link and a non-ref link. If you would like to sign up under me, I would greatly appreciate it.&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"http:\/\/csesa.me\/?r=3RQho7mRN\"&gt;http:\/\/csesa.me\/?r=3RQho7mRN&lt;\/a&gt; (my link)&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"http:\/\/www.creditsesame.com\/\"&gt;http:\/\/www.creditsesame.com\/&lt;\/a&gt; (Non-ref)&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;Mods, I have read over the rules and I don&amp;#39;t think I&amp;#39;m breaking any. Please let me know if I am or delete the thread if this is not allowed. Thanks!&lt;\/p&gt;\n&lt;\/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt;",
          "selftext": "Some of you may have seen this already, but CreditSesame is running a promo for the month of November where you refer 6 friends and receive a $150 Amazon Gift Card. I'm hoping we can get a legitimate referral train started so we can all make some easy money. Should come in handy for Christmas shopping.\n\nTHIS OFFER IS FOR THE US ONLY &amp;amp; YOU HAVE TO BE AT LEAST 18 YEARS OLD.\n\nWhat is CreditSesame?\n\nIt's pretty much just like CreditKarma. It shows you your credit score, why you got the score and what you can do to improve it.\n\nMost importantly, there is NO CREDIT CARD NEEDED to sign up because it's FREE. You can of course buy some advanced features, but that's not necessary.\n\nNow, you do have to provide legitimate information, as it uses your SSN to get your credit report. They pull your credit report in a way that won't hurt your credit score according to their site. (Someone may be able to better explain this than me)\n\nReferral Train\n\nHere are some basic guidelines to try to get this thing running smoothly: Once you sign up, you can get your referral link by hovering over your name on in the top-right corner and selecting \"Invite a friend\" from the menu. Paste that link as a reply to who you signed up under in this thread. Each person only needs 6 referrals, so don't keep signing up under someone when they already have 6 replies. Keep \"forking\" and spreading the referrals around so that everyone has at least a chance to get a few. Please remove your referral link once you receive 6 referrals so everyone knows you have completed yours. So to get this started, here is my referral link and a non-ref link. If you would like to sign up under me, I would greatly appreciate it.\n\nhttp:\/\/csesa.me\/?r=3RQho7mRN (my link)\n\nhttp:\/\/www.creditsesame.com\/ (Non-ref)\n\nMods, I have read over the rules and I don't think I'm breaking any. Please let me know if I am or delete the thread if this is not allowed. Thanks!",
          "likes": null,
          "user_reports": [

          ],
          "secure_media": null,
          "link_flair_text": null,
          "id": "2m366z",
          "gilded": 0,
          "secure_media_embed": {

          },
          "clicked": false,
          "report_reasons": null,
          "author": "EarthBrown",
          "media": null,
          "score": 5,
          "approved_by": null,
          "over_18": false,
          "hidden": false,
          "thumbnail": "self",
          "subreddit_id": "t5_2qir9",
          "edited": false,
          "link_flair_css_class": null,
          "author_flair_css_class": null,
          "downs": 0,
          "mod_reports": [

          ],
          "saved": false,
          "is_self": true,
          "name": "t3_2m366z",
          "permalink": "\/r\/deals\/comments\/2m366z\/free_150_for_6_referrals_to_credit_sesame\/",
          "stickied": false,
          "created": 1415840944,
          "url": "http:\/\/www.reddit.com\/r\/deals\/comments\/2m366z\/free_150_for_6_referrals_to_credit_sesame\/",
          "author_flair_text": null,
          "title": "Free $150 for 6 Referrals to Credit Sesame!",
          "created_utc": 1415812144,
          "ups": 5,
          "num_comments": 2,
          "visited": false,
          "num_reports": null,
          "distinguished": null
        }
      }],
    "after": "t3_2lx2yh",
    "before": null
  }
}';

$data1 = '{
  "kind": "Listing",
  "data": {
    "modhash": "mxgmpcysk5ce5f6dbb57adcc895d089f0fc5c98d08361beb37",
    "children": [
      {
        "kind": "t3",
        "data": {
          "domain": "rodneybrooksjr.com",
          "banned_by": null,
          "media_embed": {

          },
          "subreddit": "redditdeals",          
          "secure_media": null,
          "link_flair_text": null,
          "id": "2d5ad3",
          "gilded": 0,
          "secure_media_embed": {

          },
          "clicked": false,
          "report_reasons": null,
          "author": "rodneybrooksjr",
          "media": null,
          "score": 0,
          "approved_by": null,
          "over_18": false,
          "hidden": false,
          "thumbnail": "",
          "subreddit_id": "t5_2r0ax",
          "edited": false,
          "link_flair_css_class": null,
          "author_flair_css_class": null,
          "downs": 0,
          "mod_reports": [

          ],
          "saved": false,
          "is_self": false,
          "name": "t3_2d5ad3",
          "permalink": "\/r\/redditdeals\/comments\/2d5ad3\/heres_a_product_i_like_that_you_might_want_to\/",
          "stickied": false,
          "created": 1407682429,
          "url": "http:\/\/rodneybrooksjr.com\/kingston",
          "author_flair_text": null,
          "title": "Here's a product I like that you might want to check out! You can get Kingston 4GB USB Flash Drive for just $9.97 (a 44% savings!)",
          "created_utc": 1407678829,
          "ups": 0,
          "num_comments": 1,
          "visited": false,
          "num_reports": null,
          "distinguished": null
        }
      }],
    "after": "t3_1zqtxs",
    "before": null
  }
}';
```

Am i doing something wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: "Its not working, what am I doing wrong". You tell us what's wrong first.

Comment: `Am I doing something wrong?` - Not explaining what happens for instance. Error message? What's the input data? Tried something else, like converting the objects to arrays first?

Comment: [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) uses `$array1` as *keys* and `$array2` as *values* and creates an array.  That's what you want, right?

Comment: P.S. I assume `echo $data;` should be `echo $json;`?

Comment: Are you sure the results of your `json_decode()` operations are arrays and not objects?

Comment: @MikeB  Please see added error details

Comment: What are `$array1` and `$array2`?  What do they contain?  You might need to use a loop to combine them instead of trying built-in functions.

Comment: @RocketHazmat added above in my main question , please see

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `array_combine` which combines values in array1 as key and values from array2 as value you should use `array_merge($array1, $array2)` to merge two arrays

Comment: I am getting following error after changing it to array_merge , Error Details -> Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in "URL" on line 8
null , any thoughts?

Comment: This is probably because ```$array1``` not an array. Try changing decode to ```json_decode($data, true)```. The last parameter indicates that it should return result as an associated array and not as an object. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: when i add true to the decode , Output has only array2 objects , array1 objects completely missing.

Comment: ```array_merge``` function will overwrite existing keys in ```$array1``` with matching keys in ```$array2```. As i can see the two arrays has the same structure so I would guess that you want ```$json = json_encode(array($array1, $array2))```